# Unable to compose a Setting[T] with a Def.Initialize[Task[Seq[File]]] in SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am attempting to extend play-sass so it has an option of using libsass instead of a ruby sass executable on path. Play Asset Compiler plugins work by appending a `AssetsCompiler` to `resourceGenerators in Compile`, I am however having issues in getting this to work.

The current play-sass source has something like this to add the `AssetCompiler` to `resourceGenerators in Compile`

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= {
        AssetsCompiler(
        "sass",
        { file => (file ** "*.sass") +++ (file ** "*.scss") },
        sassEntryPoints,
        { (name, min) =>
          name
            .replace(".sass", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
            .replace(".scss", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
        },
        { (file, options) => SassCompiler.compile(file, options) },
        sassOptions
        )
      }
```

I want to add a new setting, called `libSass`, which is a `Setting[Key]` that allows the user to specify if they want to use libsass. The problem is that I can't actually use the value from within libsass as a parameter when calling `AssetCompiler`, i.e. doing something like this

```
resourceGenerators in Compile <+= {
        AssetsCompiler(
        "sass",
        { file => (file ** "*.sass") +++ (file ** "*.scss") },
        sassEntryPoints,
        { (name, min) =>
          name
            .replace(".sass", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
            .replace(".scss", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
        },
        { (file, options) => SassCompiler.compile(file, options,libSass.value) },
        sassOptions
        )
      }
```

`AssetCompiler` is a function that returns a `Def.Initialize[Task[Seq[File]]]`, and I have been unable to compose the value from the libSass Setting (which is a `Boolean`) so that it can be used with `SassCompiler.compile`.

Stuff like

```
libSass.toTask.map{useLibSass =>
          AssetsCompiler("sass",
          { file => (file ** "*.sass") +++ (file ** "*.scss") },
          sassEntryPoints,
          { (name, min) =>
            name
              .replace(".sass", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
              .replace(".scss", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
          },
          { (file, options) => SassCompiler.compile(file, options,useLibSass) },
          sassOptions
          )
        }
```

Doesn't work (this gives me a `Def.Initialize[Task[Def.Initialize[Task[Seq[File]]]]]`), and using flatMap won't even compile (even though, by looking at the types, it seems like what you should be doing), i.e.

```
libSass.toTask.flatMap{useLibSass =>
          AssetsCompiler("sass",
          { file => (file ** "*.sass") +++ (file ** "*.scss") },
          sassEntryPoints,
          { (name, min) =>
            name
              .replace(".sass", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
              .replace(".scss", if (min) ".min.css" else ".css")
          },
          { (file, options) => SassCompiler.compile(file, options,useLibSass) },
          sassOptions
          )
        }
```

Also using the macro version friendly versions (i.e. `+=` instead of `<+=`) doesn't work either

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work? Even though SBT is using `map`/`flatMap` composition, there doesn't seem to be any `flatten` function (common when working with monad's in Scala), and I can't seem to find any utility functions to help me out

I have also uploaded the code at https://github.com/mdedetrich/play-sass/tree/libsass